# WPF popup listbox use keyboard for navigation

Tags: wpf, listbox

Can anyone suggest the solution how can I make navigation using down and up keys in listbox which come on popup.
Solutions like set selected items on keyup and keydown event are not working for me.
Should I make something more special then just set selected item in this case?

Comment: What do you mean by popup listbox?

Comment: `ListBox` already implements selection navigation using keyboard. You only need to set focus to the `ListBox` ...

Comment: I have popup which show when I click on textbox. Popup contains Listbox

Comment: Set focus on listbox or on first listbox item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListBox` already implements selection navigation using keyboard when it is focused.

All you have to do is give it focus when you want, for example in the window that contains it:

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Down)
    {
        listbox.SelectedIndex = 0;
        listbox.Focus();
    }
}
```

Because `listbox.Focus();` will only give it focus but won't yet change the selection item (which will make the user hit's the "Down" button twice in order to do so) set the `ListBox`'s `SelectedIndex` first.

Hope this helps